# android sqlite crashing (encoding issue)

Tags: android, encoding, android-sqlite

I am a newbie to android dev, I just downloaded a ready-made package
to use it for a mini dictionary for technical words. Now the thing is
that some word explanations have special characters like: Ã‰Â™'bÃƒÂ¦k:

Below is the query that fetches words from the db. It works fine if 'WORDEX'
doesn't contain special chars, but if it does sqlite crashes and it shows:
"Unfortunately,database has stopped"

```
f (c.moveToFirst()){
                  do{
                        temp_array.add(  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("WORD")) +
                                   "," + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("WORDEX")) +
                                   "," + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("N"))                                   
                                   );
```

Among other things on stacktrace I see:

```
12-25 13:28:41.568: E/AndroidRuntime(17652): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
12-25 13:28:41.568: E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    at com.example.database.MainActivity.RunDatabse(MainActivity.java:98)
12-25 13:28:41.568: E/AndroidRuntime(17652):    ... 14 more
12-25 13:29:45.188: E/InputDispatcher(370): channel 'b4039340 com.example.database/com.example.database.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately,database has stopped, Im sure its related to encoding/special chars, since it crashes only when the database cell has special chars on it.

Comment: could you post stacktrace from logcat ?